# Migrating from ASP.NET Core RC1 to RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

in RC1 I can use nuget packages like AutoMapper or whatever on this way:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "My Class Library",
  "authors": [ "author" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MongoDB.Driver": "2.2.3"

      }
    }

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.1.1"

  }
}
```

For example, this is not working:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
      "net451": {
        "MediaTypeMap": "2.1.0",
        "AWSSDK.S3": "3.1.3.10",            
        "Mandrill.net": "2.2.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core": "1.0.0-*",
        "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
        "WindowsAzure.Storage": "6.2.0"      
    },
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

How can I do that in RC2? Thanks.

Comment: That has not changed. It still is `"dependencies":{ "Framework":"version" }`. Automapper for RC2 would be `"AutoMapper":"5.0.0-beta-1"`.

Comment: Hi @Marcus I have some errors like this: The dependency "NAME" does not support framework .NETStandard, version=1.5, I'm using in a class library.

Comment: Ok, where did you find the correct version? I'm having erros for example in RestSharp too, thanks @Marcus ;)

Comment: And with about 10 libraries more...

Comment: You will need to go through the libraries and update them accordingly. I did this myself and I updated all dependencies separately (alternatively, you setup a new RC2 project separately, install all the nuget packages you need with the NuGet Package Manager and then copy the dependencies section to your migrated project. If you Google, you will find that (example) _"EntityFramework rc1"_ will answer `EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final` and _"EntityFramework rc2"_ will answer `7.0.0-rc2-final` or `1.0.0-preview1-final`. It´s all out there :)

Comment: Thanks @Marcus again, but I can't use like RC1, for example this part: "dnx451": { }, Do I have any alternative to dnx451? Libraries not updated?

Comment: You should not target `dnx451` with RC2, target the `net451` framework instead. Look, if you want to migrate, you will have to remove the RC1 gadgets and go for the new ones. In RC2 there is no more `dnvm`, `dnu`, `dnx` toolchain, it is replaced by `dotnet`. `dnxcore50` is deprecated and replaced by `netcoreapp1.0`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know, I have read all documentation, but I'm having thousands of errors...

Comment: Why don´t you start with a new project and gradually move code?

Comment: I don' want to lose Source Control, and gulp, my project is very big in RC1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114236/discussion-between-marcus-and-chemitaxis).

Comment: I wrote a migration guide that might help you understand some of the changes. https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/